# Properly setting custom Login Redirects in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have a custom user model (subclassing AbstractUser):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _    
from .managers import UserManager

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_director = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

And a custom view to handle the sign up form:

```
class SignUpView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'form.html'
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    form_title = "Family Registration Form"
    form_description = "For our younger participants, their parent or guardian should fill out this form."

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('Participants:portal', kwargs={'slug': 'scst'})
```

Mapped by the following url:

```
path('signup/', views.SignUpView.as_view(), name="signup"),
```

The form loads and successfully creates a user. However, I can't figure out how to redirect properly. Specifically, I am looking for this:

```
http://localhost:8000/scst/portal/
```

and am getting:

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/scst/portal/
```

I don't understand how to get rid of the `/accounts/login/?next=` portion. I have searched through CreateView's various Classes and Mixins. I have tried overriding the `get_redirect_url` and I have tried setting the pattern in the `settings.py` file. There is no "next" value in either the HTML's form or submit elements. I'm at a loss of what to change to fix this.

Comment: Where exactly do you login your user, as looking by the URL you are getting user is not logged in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin

Comment: Oh interesting.. I think I understand my issue. I need to manually log them in after creating the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it happens because your view "Participants:portal" is login required, you must login new user after registration, you can do it in `form_valid` method. Like that

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def form_valid(self, form)
    response = super().form_valid(form)
    login(self.request, self.object)
    return response
```

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ty, i fixed the answer